# Java issue with Scanner (null String returned)

Tags: java

I am making an exercise for my Java studies and I am running a check with TMC plugin. I get an error:

```
FAIL: AirportTest airplanePrinting1
Verify that your program's output is exactly same as in the assignment's example
user's input was:
1
AY-123
108
x
1
x

program should have printed line "AY-123 (108 ppl)" in the right part
your program's output was after choosing [1] option:

Choose operation:
[1] Print planes
[2] Print flights
[3] Print plane info
[x] Quit
> null (0 ppl)
```

My relevant code is:

```
public class Planes {
    private String id;
    private int capacity;
    private ArrayList<Planes> myPlane;
    private Reader reader = new Reader();  
    
    public Planes() {
        this.id = id;
        this.capacity = capacity;        
        this.myPlane = new ArrayList<Planes>();        
    }
    
    public Planes(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public Planes(String id, int capacity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.capacity = capacity;        
    }
    
    public void addPlane() {
        System.out.print("Give plane ID: ");
        if(reader.reader.hasNextLine())
            this.id = reader.readString();
        //reader.reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Give plane capacity: ");
        if(reader.reader.hasNextLine())
            capacity = reader.readInt();
        Planes object = new Planes(id, capacity);
        myPlane.add(object);
    }
    
    public void printPlane() {
        for (Planes anyPlane : this.myPlane){
            System.out.println(anyPlane.id + " (" + anyPlane.capacity + " ppl)");
        }            
    }

public class Reader {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);   
            
    public String readString() {
        return reader.nextLine();        
    }
    
    public int readInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());        
    }
}

public class AirportPanel {
    private Reader reader = new Reader();
    //String command = reader.readString();
    
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Airport panel");
        System.out.println("--------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        
        Planes one = new Planes();
        Flights fly = new Flights();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose operation:");
            System.out.println("[1] Add airplane");
            System.out.println("[2] Add flight");
            System.out.println("[x] Exit");
            System.out.print("> ");
                                   
            String command = reader.readString();
            if (command.equals("1")) {
                //Planes one = new Planes();
                one.addPlane();
            } else if(command.equals("2")) {
                //Flights fly = new Flights();
                fly.addFlight();
            } else if(command.equals("x")) {
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Again: ");
        }
        
        System.out.println("Flight service");
        System.out.println("------------");
        System.out.println("");
        
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose operation:");
            System.out.println("[1] Print planes");
            System.out.println("[2] Print flights");
            System.out.println("[3] Print plane info");
            System.out.println("[x] Quit");
            System.out.print("> ");
                       
            String command = reader.readString();
            if (command.equals("1")) {
                one.printPlane();                
            } else if(command.equals("2")) {
                fly.printFlight();
            } else if(command.equals("3")) {
                one.printInfo();          
            } else if(command.equals("x")) {
                System.out.println("");
                break;
            } else
                System.out.println("Again: ");
        }
    }
}
```

I had other errors before that (NoSuchElement Exception) and I fixed it by adding

```
if(reader.reader.hasNextLine()).
```

I understand that by adding the condition I created the possibility to receive null instead of scanning for the value. How can I fix it?

Comment: I just copied your code into an IDE, added a main method, it ran exactly like you specified it should.  Are you sure the error isn't from somewhere else in your code?

Comment: The program should have printed line "AY-123 (108 ppl)", but the output was "null (0 ppl)" after choosing [1] option:

Choose operation:
[1] Print planes
[2] Print flights
[3] Print plane info
[x] Quit.   I don't know how to fix it.